# ses and outer semidirect products of groups

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $\phi : H \to Aut(N)$ be an action ($N,H$ are groups), and let $G = H \rtimes_\phi N$ be the semidirect product ($N$ is normal in $G$). I know that when $\phi$ is the action by conjugation, there is a ses $1 \to N \to G \to H \to 1$ with a section $ H \to G$. My question is

> for a general $\phi$, is there also a ses $1 \to N \to G \to H \to 1$?

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Some_equivalent_definitions_of_inner_semidirect_products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Some_equivalent_definitions_of_inner_semidirect_products), can you prove the definitions are equivalent?

Comment: What does "the action by conjugation" mean? You have specified that $H$ and $N$ are different groups. But the answer to the question is yes, because in any semidirect product $G$ of $N$ by $H$ we have $G/N \cong H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt By 'action by conjugation' I mean that $\phi(h)(n) = h n h^{-1}$ (maybe I should have specified that $H \leq G$). Also, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @whacka Thanks, that settles it.